# If $\quad f(x)+xf'(x)+f''(x)=0, $ prove that $f(x)=e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We know that: $$ 0 < f(x)\leq1 , \forall x \in R\quad ,f(0)=1$$
$$ and \quad f(x)+xf'(x)+f''(x)=0 \quad \forall x \in R$$
I am asked to prove that $$ f(x)=e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$

What I have tried is:
If we rewrite the expression as:
$$ (x)'f(x)+xf'(x)+(f'(x))'=0 \Rightarrow (xf(x)+f'(x))'=0 \Rightarrow xf(x)+f'(x)=c_1 $$
Then, by following a quite known methodology for these types of problems, I try:
$$ f'(x)+(\frac{x^2}{2})'f(x)=c_1 \Rightarrow e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}f'(x)+(e^{\frac{x^2}{2}})'f(x)=c_1e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\Rightarrow (e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}f(x))'=c_1e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

I only have left to prove that the right part equals one, so I can then divide by $$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}>0, $$ and get the wanted f(x). Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Any differential equation of the form $$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=g'(x)\dfrac{dy}{dx}+g''(x)y$$ has a particular solution of the form $y=e^{g(x)}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. From $(e^{x^2/2}f(x))'=c_1e^{x^2/2}$, just integrate and you find
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^x(e^{t^2/2}f(t))'\, dt=c_1\int_0^xe^{t^2/2}\, dt \\
&\implies e^{x^2/2}f(x)-f(0)=c_1\int_0^xe^{t^2/2}\, dt \\
&\implies f(x)=f(0)e^{-x^2/2}+c_1e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^xe^{t^2/2}\, dt
\end{align*}
Finally, we know $f(0)=1$. Moreover, the equation $f(x)+xf'(x)+f''(x)=0$ implies that $f''(0)=-1$. This fact should allow you to solve for $c_1$. You could invoke theorems, but this way is arriving at the answer by seeing the calculations for yourself.

Comment: I am sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, but how can I calculate the last integral from 0 to x? In my school, we have learned why this is actually true, but have never actually used it in a problem, so I am kinda lost. If you could explain that a bit more, it would be great =) and thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: Not a dumb question at all! It turns out, you don't need to. When you differentiate twice and plug in $0$, the integral will vanish. Not only do you not need to, it cannot be done using elementary methods. Also, note that you should find $c_1=0$ so when you do get the answer, the strange integral isn't there anyways.

Comment: Oh okay! I figured out another solution, due to $f(x) \leq 1 \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(0)$ , so using Fermat's Theorum, as f has an extremality on $x_0 = 0$, so $f(0)=0$. Then I go to the equality where I have $xf(x)+f'(x)= c_1$ and by plugging 0, I get that c=0, as intended. Either way, thanks for the answer, I will still write it in my response (small flex intended). Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I like your way far better. When I read the problem initially, I thought it was only defined for $x\geq 0$ so we didn't know if $0$ was a critical point. From your suggestion, you can say $xf(x)+f'(x)=0$ so $f(x)=Ce^{-x^2/2}$. Then $f(0)=1$ shows $C=1$.